Render paragraph with eFrame + eGui
I have successfully displayed a heading with the following code and I want to add a paragraph. The paragraph must be selectable but not editable. How can I do it?
Here's my code:
use eframe;
pub struct Gui;

impl eframe::App for Gui {
    fn update(&mut self, ctx: &egui::Context, frame: &mut eframe::Frame) {
        egui::CentralPanel::default().show(ctx, |ui| {
            ui.heading("Hello there");
            // ui.paragraph("General Kenobi");
        });
    }
}


You probably want ui.label() which can be used like this:
impl eframe::App for Gui {
    fn update(&mut self, ctx: &egui::Context, frame: &mut eframe::Frame) {
        egui::CentralPanel::default().show(ctx, |ui| {
            ui.heading("Hello there");
            ui.label("General Kenobi");
        });
    }
}

